# In Rails Can we pass a parameters to a new Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

i  would like to write a message using an instince variable in the new invition action like this. redirect_to new_invitation_path("invite your friend")

Controller invitations:

```
def new(message)
 @message = message
 @from_user_id = facebook_session.user.to_s
end
```

Apparently it is not possible how can i find a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that redirect_to goes through the client, so you might need to use params[] for that

Answer (score 2):

You might want to clarify your question, but wouldn't a `flash` message solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, flash is designed exactly for this scenario

Comment: i am using Facebooker library and flash doesnt work proprely .I have to find another way

Comment: Then just pass it as a get parameter in your uri.